# Understanding the scope of a class variable in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder structure like this:

```
.
├── db
│   └── mysqldb1.py
└── helpers
    ├── __pycache__
    └── context.py
```

`helper/context.py` contains a Singleton class like:

```
class Context():
    g = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'blah'
        self.b = 'blabla'
        self.conn = None

    @classmethod
    def init_g(cls):
        if not cls.g:
             cls.g = cls()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Context.init_g()
    from db.mysqldb1 import get_conn
    Context.g.conn = get_conn()
```

In `db.mysqldb1.py` I have:

```
from helpers.context import Context

def get_conn():
    a = Context.g.a
    b = Context.g.b
    ... # more logic
```

When I execute `python -m helpers.context` from root folder, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/ttomson/Codes/test/helpers/context.py", line 17, in <module>
    Context.g.conn = get_conn()
  File "/Users/ttomson/Codes/test/db/mysqldb1.py", line 4, in get_conn
    a = Context.g.a
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```

The python interpreter complains that Context.g was never initialized. Why is that the case?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Context.init_g()
```

Did I not initialize it when I executed the above? Please help me understand this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope; it is because you wrote `if __name__ == '__main__':` to guard the code which initialises that attribute. If you want the field to be initialised unconditionally, why guard it?

Comment: @kaya3: It's more complex than that. The guarded code does actually run, but there are two versions of the module, and only one is initialized.

Comment: @kaya3: Does that mean each time I do something like:
`from helpers.context import Context`, all of the codes of `helper/context.py` get executed a second time?

Comment: You have two versions of the class in memory: `__main__.Context` and `helper.context.Context`. This happens when you reimport the module you are executing.

Answer (score 4):

This is a weird interaction between `__main__` and circular imports. The fix is to change your code to avoid circular imports.

When you run `python -m helpers.context`, Python runs a version of `helpers.context` as the `__main__` module, **separate** from the regular `helpers.context` module. This version runs the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, and initializes its own version of `Context`.

`db.mysqldb1` tries to import `helpers.context`, and it gets the regular version of `helpers.context`. This version never initialized its `Context.g`, which is why you get the AttributeError.